# Bad Request response when executing stored procedures from DocumentDBs Node driver

Tags: node.js, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

Right now I'm exploring stored procedures on DocumentDb and I'm trying to do a hello world test. I can confirm that the stored procedure exists because it is returned when I query all of the stored procedures(I'm gonna start saying sproc now). I'm using the Node driver and all other queries, inserts, and deletions have gone through. Here is a snippet I've run:

```
client.executeStoredProcedure( 
    'dbs/fun-db/colls/my-coll/sprocs/testSproc', //path to sproc
    { partitionKey: ['2017-08-15'] }, //options
    (err, response) => { //callback
        if(err) console.error(err)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
    }
)
```

this is what is printed to the console:

```
{ 
    code: 400,
    body: '{
        "code":"BadRequest",
        "message":"Message: {\\"Errors\\":[\\"The partition key supplied in x-ms-partitionkey header has fewer components than defined in the the collection.\\"]}\\r\\nActivityId: e696b9e2-8ce4-4343-abd3-62faab04eac2, Request URI: /apps/eef89563-3ff8-4aa9-b087-aa280317b73d/services/18fc5ba1-10e1-40c2-880f-0a2a89c36b7f/partitions/b4910dfa-a34e-4332-9f2b-632139db609e/replicas/131478338408915195p/"
    }',
    activityId: 'e696b9e2-8ce4-4343-abd3-62faab04eac2',
    substatus: 1001 
}
```

I set up my partitions based on date and I set the options.partitionKey to be a value I know exists in a partition. With the chance that the partitionKey needs to be date(the parameter on the documents) I also tried that with the same result.

Comment: Try putting `undefined` in the second parameter call to `client.executeStoredProcedure`. I'm wondering if it thinks your options object is actually a parameter for the sproc.

Comment: My other thought is that the array value for partitionKey might need to be a string now. I seem to recall that it used to be specified as an array but that it accepted a string but I now see that the docs say it should be a string. Maybe they no longer like it to be an array... or maybe my memory is off.

Comment: If either of those fix the problem, let me know and I'll create an answer you can accept.

Comment: The undefined addition did the trick! Thanks so much Larry!

Answer (score 0):

Put undefined in the second parameter call to client.executeStoredProcedure. It thinks your options object is actually a parameter for the sproc.